# Open phonegap application when click to a specific url

Tags: cordova

This is similar to intents in android, what i need is when clicking a specific url format in a browser through mobile device installed phonegap application should start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit your App *Info-.plist file and define URL Schemes for example "myapp://"

When the user tries to open a link that starts with myapp:// then your App will open

Here is a good tutorial
http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

Comment: Thanks you for the support, I was able to use this [LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/LaunchMyApp-PhoneGap-Plugin) to get the work done, I have written an article for others if someone else get the same problem in here [Adding Custom URL Schema in Phonegap App](http://imalhasaranga.com/2014/04/18/adding-custom-url-schema-in-phonegap-app/)